# Can yfinance download 2 columns only?

Tags: python, yfinance

Right now, I want to download historical prices for some tickers but I don't need the full download, only the date and close price.

Currently I am doing this way :

```
with open("tickers_list.txt") as fp:
    Lines = fp.readlines()
    for line in Lines: #for each line = ticker
        line = line.strip() #remove "/n" in the line
        data = yf.download(line,period = '10y', interval='1d')
        del data["Open"] #remove useless column
        del data["High"] #remove useless column
        del data["Low"] #remove useless column
        del data["Adj Close"] #remove useless column
        del data["Volume"] #remove useless column
        data.to_csv('download/'+line+'.csv')

# close the file
fp.close()
```

As you can see, I download the whole "package" then delete the useless columns.
The future problem with this way is : if I need to download data for 10'000 companies, I will lose quite sometimes in the process.

Normal download

```
yf.download(line,period = '10y', interval='1d')
Date        Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  Volume
2012-04-23  409.200012  410.899994  398.700012  402.399994  331.590271  203708
2012-04-24  408.600006  412.299988  406.700012  408.500000  336.616821  204588
```

what I am looking for

```
yf.download(line,period = '10y', interval='1d', [Date], [Close])
Date        Close
2012-04-23  402.399994
2012-04-24  408.500000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = yf.Ticker("IBM").history(start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30", frequency='1dy')['Close']
```

Returns only one price

Output:

```
Date
2017-01-03    125.567116
2017-01-04    127.121788
2017-01-05    126.701187
2017-01-06    127.324532
2017-01-09    125.912628
                 ...    
2017-04-24    121.685005
2017-04-25    121.412483
2017-04-26    121.162666
2017-04-27    121.359474
2017-04-28    121.336777
```

Also, if you request all the data, you can try to delete the unnecessary immediately

```
data = yf.download("AAPL", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30", auto_adjust=True)
data = data[['Close']]
print(data)
```

Comment: Amazing ! thanks ! it works perfectly this way 
`data = yf.download(line,period = '10y', interval='1d')['Close']`